# How to programmatically create Windows user accounts on Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008?

Tags: c#, windows-7

I've been trying to create new local user accounts on windows 7 machine. I used the System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry class (as in [here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;306273)) but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's the code in the article:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
try
    {
 DirectoryEntry AD = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + 
                     Environment.MachineName + ",computer");
 DirectoryEntry NewUser = AD.Children.Add("TestUser1", "user");
 NewUser.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] {"#12345Abc"});
 NewUser.Invoke("Put", new object[] {"Description", "Test User from .NET"});
 NewUser.CommitChanges();
 DirectoryEntry grp;

 grp = AD.Children.Find("Guests", "group");
 if (grp != null) {grp.Invoke("Add", new object[] {NewUser.Path.ToString()});}
 Console.WriteLine("Account Created Successfully");
 Console.ReadLine();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
 Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
 Console.ReadLine();

}
}
```

When executing this line

`DirectoryEntry NewUser = AD.Children.Add("TestUser1", "user");`

I get a

`System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException` with "`{"Unknown error (0x80005000)"}`"

as the exception message, and `-2147463168` as the error code.

I assume this is probably because the article targets Windows XP and below machines, and I'm targeting windows 7 and Windows server 2008.

Any help appreciated! 
 
**Update:** 
*For some mysterious reason, i'm no longer seeing that `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException`, however, when committing the changes here `newuser.CommitChanges()`, I get a "`UnAuthorizedAccessException`". I tried running the app as administrator, but still not working.*

**Update 2:** 
OK, after changing to the UserPrincipal class, i got the follwoing code to work:

```
public UserPrincipal CreateNewUser(string sUserName, string sPassword)
        {
            // first check that the user doesn't exist
            if (GetUser(sUserName) == null)
            {
                PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = GetPrincipalContext();

                UserPrincipal oUserPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(oPrincipalContext);
                oUserPrincipal.Name = sUserName;
                oUserPrincipal.SetPassword(sPassword);
                //User Log on Name
                //oUserPrincipal.UserPrincipalName = sUserName;
                oUserPrincipal.Save();

                return oUserPrincipal;
            }

            // if it already exists, return the old user
            return GetUser(sUserName);
        }
    }
```

This code runs well when I run it as a console app -of course run as administrator- but when i deployed it as a windows service, with the security account set as "LocalSystem", i get an `InvlaidOperationException` saying "The underlying store does not support this property"

Thoughts?

Comment: did you run the application elevated?

Comment: you mean "As Administrator"? Yes. Same error.

Comment: That error actually means "The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist". Whether that explanation helps or not is another story.

Comment: Update 2 isn't much use to fellow travellers without the missing code, which I think may have come from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199667/finding-a-user-through-the-groupprincipal

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, if you check my last update, the following snippet worked:

```
public UserPrincipal CreateNewUser(string sUserName, string sPassword)
        {
            // first check that the user doesn't exist
            if (GetUser(sUserName) == null)
            {
                PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = GetPrincipalContext();

                UserPrincipal oUserPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(oPrincipalContext);
                oUserPrincipal.Name = sUserName;
                oUserPrincipal.SetPassword(sPassword);
                //User Log on Name
                //oUserPrincipal.UserPrincipalName = sUserName;
                oUserPrincipal.Save();

                return oUserPrincipal;
            }

            // if it already exists, return the old user
            return GetUser(sUserName);
        }
    }
```

That worked as a console app, but failed to execute due to security exceptions when deployed as a windows service. A solution is to trust that assembly (the windows service assembly) so that the .net security will let it run. That's done, now everything is cool!

Comment: Galilyou, could you elaborate on how exactly you got this working in a Windows service please?

Comment: Where is the definition for GetUser?

Comment: Thanks to Stephen Kennedy, I found GetUser here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199667/finding-a-user-through-the-groupprincipal

Comment: Dont forget to dispose oPrincipalContext and oUserPrincipal

Answer (score 0):

You need to prefix your username with CN=, like so:

`DirectoryEntry NewUser = AD.Children.Add("CN=TestUser1", "user");`

Comment: Thanks Warren, but this didn't seem to help much, though.